# Rxjs Pipes parameter values

Tags: angular

Can I do this at all? Sorry very new to angular

```
 this.route.paramMap
.pipe( map( p => p.get( 'id' ) ) )
.pipe(
    switchMap( id => this.MyService.getMyProjectData( +id ) ),
    map( items => this.MyListMapper( items, +id ) )  // I want to pass the id here from first pipe
    )
```

In the second pipe, I want to use the same parameter value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can :

```
this.route.paramMap
.pipe( 
      map( p => p.get( 'id' ) ) , 
      switchMap( id => this.MyService.getMyProjectData( +id )
                          .pipe( map( items => this.MyListMapper( items, +id ) ) )
          )
   );
```